# "failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused" in TravisCI

Tags: postgresql, perl, github, travis-ci, mojolicious

I use TravisCI to test pull requests, branches and mergers on GitHub, everything works fine until the last update (March 1, 2022), after that update I keep getting this error:

> DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::catch {...} (): DBI Connection failed: DBI connect('dbname=test;host=127.0.0.1;port=15432','postgres',...) failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
> Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 15432? at /home/travis/build/local/lib/perl5/DBIx/Class/Storage/DBI.pm line 1639. at /home/travis/build/lib/PerlFile.pm line 29

The project I'm working on is made with `Perl 5.30`, `Mojolicious` and `Postgresql`.

The problem is, I have no idea why this error occurred after this update on Travis. I've looked at the changes they've made, but there's nothing that could harm the projects or the tests. The reason I ask this question is that I hope someone else has gone through the same situation and could help me.

One note, the project started in 2017, so some of the technologies have a fairly old version, for example, Postgresql version 9.4, because today the newest is 13. I'm not sure if the older version would be a problem, but this it's the only thing I can point out.

Comment: How are you setting up your Travis CI environment? How are you launching the Postgres database?

Comment: Can you connect  using psql from the same environment?

Comment: Have you tried adding debugging output to travis execution ?`echo $(sudo cat /etc/postgresql/9/main/postgresql.conf)` will output postgres'conf. Look for "port =" and you will be able to check the actual port configured on travis machine. Note you can adapt postgresql's version as needed here: `/etc/postgresql/**your version**/main/`